# How do Latin American Spanish speakers acquire vosotros forms?

Tags: sociolinguistics, language-acquisition, spanish

In travels throughout Latin America, during which I spoke Spanish learned in Spain, local people had no problem understanding my use of *vosotros* forms even if they lived in very isolated rural areas and had only a few years of schooling. I know that they were familiar with the exact conjugation of *vosotros*, because they might even repeat back my statement, e.g. “Ayer Usted preguntó ‘¿cómo hacéis esta comida?’, pues, hacemos así…”.

I suppose that in countries with *vos* or familiar with *vos*, they assume *vosotros* works more or less the same. But how does that explain e.g. isolated *rancheros* in Baja California, in non-*vos* Mexico, being familiar with *vosotros*?

For example, has radio in Latin American (since many communities got TV only recently) presented *vosotros* forms often enough for any child to grow up learning them? If so, in what context would Latin American radio do that?

Comment: Note that basically all the countries have some regional voseo, even Mexico.  The only exceptions I can find are small island countries, like Puerto Rico and the Dominican Republic.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/por-qu%C3%A9-se-usa-vosotros-en-biblias-latinoamericanas

Answer (score 5):

*Vosotros* is used in **the Bible**, which is a corpus that many people in Latin America are exposed to at least weekly.

This makes it similar to English *ye* or *thou*, though in English there are many more updated translations floating around that don’t use those words.

Also, people are exposed to voseo on radio, television and the internet.  There are pockets of voseo in every single mainland Spanish-speaking country in Latin America, even Mexico, and Cuba.

(The question mentions the assumption that voseo makes it easy to understand *vosotros* and its verb forms.)

In fact, people are even occasionally directly exposed to Spanish from Spain, for example in interviews with football players and coaches.

So, church, music, football… All pretty strong forces.

Comment: Due to the “I bet”, and the very brief mention of the Bible that doesn’t meet Stack Exchange standards for detail, I unfortunately cannot accept this as an answer.

Comment: Sure @ChristopherC., updated.

Comment: My comment stands. This seems like taking a guess instead of having firsthand expertise on the subject, and it is still undetailed. Hopefully someone else will give this a shot.

Comment: Is the issue that you need more evidence that the Bible uses *vosotros*, or that people are exposed to the Bible, or something else?

Comment: it would probably help to specify which translation you're talking about, and evidence that it's a widely used one. This idea does seem plausible though

Comment: @Tristan Like most people, I don’t know the names of any Bible translations, it’s just how it is.  If you just Google *la biblia* and go to a verse with 2nd person plural like Corinthians 2, it’ll use *vosotros*, no matter what version you stumble upon.  There are even questions on Spanish SE based on this reality, eg https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/por-qué-se-usa-vosotros-en-biblias-latinoamericanas.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer I very much doubt that most people commenting on SE (either any of the English-language sites, or Spanish) can't name _any_ Bible translations. Regardless, identifying a specific widely used translation with vosotros rather than expecting the reader to do so would be a significant improvement to this answer. I think it would also help address (at least some of) OP's concerns

Comment: For instance, if you can identify the Spanish translation most commonly used by the Catholic Church and demonstrate that it uses vosotros, then that, together with statistics on the proportion of the Mexican population who are Catholic would be a much stronger argument than the way this currently stands